# Transform.LookAt() but only in X-Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I use my GameObject to follow the function for Transform.LookAt() only to rotate in the direction of X-Axis, by keeping Y and Z axes unchanged?

```
transform.LookAt(otherObject.transform);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead passing the whole object transform just pass on the parameters the other object x value and for the y and z use the currenct values

```
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(otherObject.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
```

Comment: I think this is a nice answer. You can see a thread about this question but on Y axis at Unity forum : https://answers.unity.com/questions/36255/lookat-to-only-rotate-on-y-axis-how.html

Comment: Is there a way to limit the rotation of transform.lookAt() using Clamp? So that the object only moves within the limit of -30 and 30 degree angles?

Comment: Here's what you can do:     <code>     
void LockedRotation()
    {
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sensitivityY;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, -rotationAngle, rotationAngle);
      
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.localEulerAngles.x, rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.z);
    }