# Limit angle of Transform.LookAt() at X-Axis and not limiting the rotation of axes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I limit the angle of X-axis through the function Transform.LookAt() so that the angle is always between (-30,30) and does not go above 30 and below -30.

```
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(otherObject.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform.LookAt() but only in X-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000766/transform-lookat-but-only-in-x-axis)

Comment: @Draco18s nope .. of you look closely OP is actually using the code from the example but the question is about limiting the angle itself not limiting the rotation to one axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik you could use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) instead and use

```
var direction = new Vector3(otherObject.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z) - transform.position;
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

rotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(rotation.eulerAngles.x, -30, 30), rotation.eulerAngles.y, rotation.eulerAngles.z);

transform.rotation = rotation;
```

---

*Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*